# Crop SVG with Inkscape

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg

I have an SVG built up by adding several images on top of each other. It works fine but the edges do not line up and overlap in ways that I don't want. I basically want to "trim" the edges of my SVG to remove this.

I'm not currently familiar enough with either SVG or Inkscape to know how to crop something in the same way you would if you was cropping e.g. a JPEG.

I'd like to be able to simply delete everything outside the viewbox. How do I do this with Inkscape?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do clipping masks exist in Inkscape?

Answer (score 1):

See the cartoon:

[image]

1. An image, the leftmost and rightmost shapes have some exessive width, everything should be limited to the width of the black rectangle
2. Duplicate the black rectangle or draw a new on top, stretch the height.
3. Select all. Goto Object > Clip > Set. It's a clipping mask.

Beware:everything is still selectable and movable. If you move something, you create easily a difficult to fix mess. Be sure you have a non-clipped copy.

Another way: Fix the edge shapes with the node tool or by making path subtractions => you have not anything hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Inkscape extension [inx-pathops](https://gitlab.com/moini_ink/inx-patho) by Moini.

If you make an object to "crop" or "clip" your vector art, i.e. you want to remove everything outside that object, select all objects, then do `Extensions > Boolean Operations > Intersection`

- https://gitlab.com/moini_ink/inx-patho (Inkscape versions over 1.0)
- https://gitlab.com/su-v/inx-pathops (Inkscape versions before 1.0)